# Is Stream.of(item).collect(Collectors.toSomeCollection()) faster than new SomeCollection(Arrays.asList(item))?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

Java 8 provides

```
Stream.of(item).collect(Collectors.toSomeCollection())
```

e.g. `Stream.of("abc").collect(Collectors.toSet())`. Is the avoidance of the relative expensive `new` operator in front of the curtain faster than

```
new SomeCollection(Arrays.asList(item))
```

e.g. `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("abc"))`?

I'm sure that initialization of different collections with `new` has different costs (a hash set needs a hashtable before being ready to use, an array list an allocated array whereas a linked list needs none of such).

I'm trying to figure out whether stream-related classes avoid `new` internally, but the OpenJDK code is hard to understand. I think they could if I'm thinking of `Stream.of` as an already initialized pipe and the collector using reusable functions.

Could it be the other way around?

Comment: What makes you think that streams avoid the `new` operator, internally?

Comment: Is this an actual performance bottleneck in your code? If not, use the form you find most readable. Personally, I think the non stream version is better.

Comment: well creating a stream is a really cheap operation although `collect(Collectors.toSomeCollection())` will internally use the new operator to construct the collection.

Comment: @AndyTurner I added an explanation to the question. It's a bit speculative, I have to admit. It seemed reasonable at first, now silly. I'll leave it here for reference.

Comment: If you don't need a mutable collection and are using Java 9, I'd suggest using `List.of`, `Set.of` or `Map.of`.

Comment: @JornVernee if you're only creating singleton collections, `Collections.singleton*` methods have existed for much longer, and are also immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, `Stream.of(item).collect(Collectors.toSomeCollection())` could return a more efficient collection, as the exact collection type is intentionally unspecified.

In practice, there are some obstacles preventing this. E.g. the collector has to [provide a supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#supplier--) for the container to accumulate the elements, without any hints about the stream characteristics, even if they are known in advance like in the `Stream.of(item)` example, which is known to have a single element. A collector could provide a supplier for an intermediate type that gets converted to a different result type at the end, which could add to memory efficiency, but would require additional CPU time.

---

This leads to the situation that, e.g. `Arrays.asList(stream.toArray())` could turn out to be more efficient than `stream.collect(Collectors.toList())`, as the `toArray()` operation can access the stream *size* if predictable. But for a stream created via `Stream.of(item[,items])` having no intermediate operations, that obviously can’t be more efficient than `Arrays.asList(item[,items])` which creates a `List` in the first place without the Stream machinery.

But for a single item, `Collections.singletoList(item)` or Java 9’s `List.of(item)` are even more efficient, as they don’t have to deal with arrays at all.

---

For creating a `Set`, the differences are even bigger, as demonstrated with actual numbers in [Jorn Vernee’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48486634/2711488).

To understand them, we have to realize that in each of the “baseline”, “asList”, and “collectStream” variants, a `HashSet` is created. Even in current Java 9, `HashSet` is still implemen­ted as a wrapper around a `HashMap`, which reduces code size but not heap size and, of course, doesn’t add to efficiency.

So in all these three variants, a single element set instance consists of a `HashSet` instance, a `HashMap` instance, an array (of entries) instance and a `Map.Entry` implementation instance. This weight is carried in all three variants.

During the `HashSet`’s construction in the “asList” variant, an array for the varargs parameter is created and `Arrays.asList` creates a wrapper around it.

In contrast, the “collectStream” variant can settle on an optimized single argument `Stream.of` variant, but it still bears the creation of a stream builder holding the item (which acts as `Spliterator`) and a `Stream` implementation instance operating upon it.

Also both, “asList” and “collectStream”, will process conditionals internally as there will be an iteration over the source, regardless of its form, to add all elements to the `HashSet`, whereas in the “baseline” variant, the knowledge that there will be only one element added has been encoded directly.

In contrast, `Collections.singleton` and `Set.of` both create a `Set` implementation instance just wrapping a single reference. That’s the most efficient form and there are no runtime evaluations necessary to decide that this form has to be used.

In this example, even hashing has to be considered as a negative performance aspect. While hashing scales great with large numbers of elements, it’s an obsolete operation for the single element case, which is not done by the specialized single-element `Set` implementations.

Answer (score 8):

Lets measure (using [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)) and find out which one is 'faster':

```
@BenchmarkMode({ Mode.AverageTime })
@Warmup(iterations = 10)
@Measurement(iterations = 10)
@Fork(1)
public class MyBenchmark {

    private static final int ITERATIONS = 10_000_000;

    @Benchmark
    public void baseLine(Blackhole bh) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            Set<String> s = new HashSet<>();
            s.add("A");
            bh.consume(s);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void asList(Blackhole bh) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            Set<?> s = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("A"));
            bh.consume(s);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void collectStream(Blackhole bh) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            Set<?> s = Stream.of("A").collect(Collectors.toSet());
            bh.consume(s);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void setOf(Blackhole bh) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            Set<?> s = Set.of("A");
            bh.consume(s);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void singletonCollection(Blackhole bh) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            Set<?> s = Collections.singleton("A");
            bh.consume(s);
        }
    }

}
```

And the results are:

```
# JMH version: 1.19
# VM version: JDK 9, VM 9+181

Benchmark                        Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
MyBenchmark.baseLine             avgt   10  0.301 ± 0.002   s/op
MyBenchmark.asList               avgt   10  0.350 ± 0.012   s/op    
MyBenchmark.collectStream        avgt   10  0.517 ± 0.009   s/op
MyBenchmark.setOf                avgt   10  0.057 ± 0.001   s/op
MyBenchmark.singletonCollection  avgt   10  0.057 ± 0.001   s/op
```

So out of the 2 you mention, using `asList` seems faster. If you only have a single element, you can use `Collections.singleton*` (as suggested by @AndyTurner). The Java 9 interface factory method goes up to any number of elements but is also optimized for single elements.

Comment: This is the exact way to find out in case you really need to (or are curious enough and don’t get tempted to use other than the most readable version in your production code). The results are valid on the computer and under the conditions where the benchmark is run and for collections of one element.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you for mentioning that. I also want to add that this only measures creation, not lookup or iteration for instance. Though I thought the results of the last 2 benchmarks were good to show too, as they use specialized 1 element `Set` implementations. So in the end 'it depends', but yeah, this is how I'd find out.

Comment: I'm not surprised that the `asList` approach is faster than the stream approach, but I am surprised there is the order of magnitude difference between those and the `Set.of` and singleton approaches. Not disbelieving, just surprised it is that big! For comparison, could you add `Set<String> s = new HashSet<>(); s.add("A");` to the benchmark?

Comment: @AndyTurner well both of these have in common that they don't allocate any dynamic Collections or arrays at all - they are just wrappers around a single reference.

Comment: @JornVernee why would you iterate *yourself* here? JMH is all against that to begin with and also why use `BlackHole`s, these are only to test methods that would return `void` and there would be no other way to do it differently (at least that would be the main case). I am sort of confused

Comment: @Eugene If you don't iterate the time it takes to run the method is too short to be meaningfully measured. The black hole is used so that the created set goes _somewhere_ and can not just be eliminated.

Comment: @JornVernee I don't think there is something "too short" for benchmarks, there would a diff between something and something else, which is measurable. As far as blackholes goes, just return the `Set`, `List`, etc, that would prevent it to go away.

Comment: @Eugene Oh yes it can be too short. For instance, if it's in the order of nano seconds it is undistinguishable from chatter caused by for instance OS thread scheduling and context switching. Normally you'd generate a large data set to operate on, but the question asks about use with a single element. Returning would work, but we have to iterate, and can only return once, so we have to use a black hole.

Comment: @JornVernee agreed about the noise caused by the OS, that is why I usually let these tests run for 1-2 hours so that noise is amortized. Anyway, I doubt I will have time to play with it any different... thank you for comments

Answer (score 1):

A collector of `List`, `Set` or `Map` will finally create a `List`, `Set` or `Map` instance.
For example here is the `Collectors.toSet()` body :

```
public static <T>
Collector<T, ?, Set<T>> toSet() {
    return new CollectorImpl<>((Supplier<Set<T>>) HashSet::new, Set::add,
                               (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },
                               CH_UNORDERED_ID);
}
```

So you will never spare the `new` operator statement.

`Stream.of()` allows to manipulate a `Stream`.
I think that it is the single valid reason to use it.